# Strange boxes with numbers in Firefox on Windows

Tags: firefox

Has anybody an idea where these strange boxes come from?

[image]

See: http://moargh.de/themes/mireille-hofwijk/about/

I checked it on Windows 7 with Firefox v4.0.
On Windows 7 with Firefox v12.0 they don’t appear.

The content on the website is generated with WordPress.

Comment: I am fairly confident that this is caused by you not having the proper font installed required to view that text.

Comment: It can be an encoding issue aswell.

Comment: @leigero: It’s a webfont.